# Portion of my php is displaying in the browser

Tags: php

I am trying to add php to my website to send an email when the user clicks a submit button. For some reason, a section of my php is displaying in the browser and I can't figure out why. I've looked up information and tried checking my quotes and things like that, but I don't see what would be causing a portion of it to display as text.

[image: ScreenShot of php]

```
<?php
    $action=$_REQUEST['action'];

    if ($action=="") /* display the contact form */
    {
?>
        <form id="Contact-Form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row">
                <label for="name">Your name:</label><br />
                    <input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="email">Your email:</label><br />
                    <input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="message">Your message:</label><br />
                    <textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br />
            </div>
            <input id="Submit-Button" type="submit" value="Send email" />
        </form> 
<?php
    } 
    else /* send the submitted data */
    {
        $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
        $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
        $message=$_REQUEST['message'];

        if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
        {
            echo "All fields are required, please fill the form again.";
        }
        else
        {        
            $from="From: $name<$email>\r\n Return-path: $email";
            $subject="Message sent using your contact form";
            mail("email@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from);
            echo "Email sent!";
        }
    }  
?>
```

Comment: is this a *.php file?

Comment: this php is inside my html file.

Comment: unless your server parses *.html as php, that's what happens

Comment: well i wrote the file in notepad++ and then opened it with Google Chrome to see how it looked. And only a portion of the php is displaying as text. not all of it.

Comment: do you have php installed locally? and a webserver? -if so you then need to view the url `http://localhost ..`. NOT `file:/// ...`

Comment: no. the file is going to be uploaded to a webhost when its completed though.

Comment: well you can't *process* the php without a webserver (and php), its parsed raw to the browser, which is going to guess its html, and display it

Comment: oh so is there a way to create a form that sends an email from a webpage without php?

Comment: no. well not with out some server side language - unless you wanted to call the users email client with a  `mailto` link

Answer (score 1):

To explain why this happens...

Notice how the portion of code shown is only the bit after `<$email>` in your code? Specifically that `>`.

When you open a PHP file in your browser without a server processing it first, most PHP code will be seen by the browser as just one big, invalid HTML tag and will not be shown, except in View Source and document inspector tools. However, since your code happens to contain a `>`, this marks the end of the "invalid HTML tag" and anything after it will be seen in the page.

To fix this, use a server! PHP has one built-in as of 5.4, so if you have it installed on your machine you can open a command line in the root folder of your PHP and run:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Then open a browser and go to `http://localhost:8000/yourfile.php` and it will run. Nifty!